# Whats wrong with this mediaquery?

Tags: css, media-queries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [whats wrong with the media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060657/whats-wrong-with-the-media-query)

[W3C standards doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) says:

> User agents are to represent a media query as "not all" when one of the specified media features is not known.

Then it gives following example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-weight: 3kg) and (color), (color)" href="example.css" />
```

It then says that the first media query will be represented as "not all" and evaluate to false and the second media query is evaluated as if the first had not been specified, effectively.

Why is it like that. I hope that's because 3kg value for max-weight, which is not specified. However I cant see any unknown media-feature but "Unknown media feature value", which is discussed separately in the document just after "Unknown media features". I think this example should have been put below "Unknown media feature value" but not in "Unknown media features".